# Jquery: slideDown stop before reaching top

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am using jquery to slide down an `hr` tag on hover. An example of this is on the airware site (when you hover over the menu items) [Airware](http://www.airware.com/).

My problem is that I am trying to make the `hr` tag disappear before it reaches the menu item above.

For example:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>Link<hr/></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
hr{ display:none }
li{ display:inline }
```

js

```
var $nav = $('nav li');
$nav.hover(function(){
    if($(this).find('hr').is(":hidden")){
        $(this).find('hr').slideDown(400);
    }
},function(){
    if($(this).find('hr').is(":visible")){
        $(this).find('hr').slideUp(400);
    }

});
```

When the hr tag slides up I want it to stop at a certain point and return to display:none. I want to do this so that the hr tag does not get to close to the text above it. 
Feel free to ask if the question doesn't make complete sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fadeout with a slightly less time, and then dequeue the slide animation so that both of them happen at the same time.

http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/ek7gmfdm/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav = $('nav li');
    $nav.hover(function () {
        if ($(this).find('hr').is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).find('hr').slideDown(400);
        }
    }, function () {
        if ($(this).find('hr').is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find('hr').slideUp({queue:false, duration:400});
            $( this ).find('hr').fadeOut(300);
        }

    });
});
```